# Is there a better way to use the loop in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a calendar custom post type in wordpress. I have it working fine in my template, but I know there is a better way to run through the loop. I used a custom taxonomy for the month (January, February, March, etc...) and am sorting the posts month-by-month on the page. At the moment, that means I am having to run 12 separate loops to get the functionality I am wanting, which I'm sure is not the right way to go about it.

Here is the code I am working with, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div class="module">
<h2>January</h2>
<?php // Annual Events Posts
$calendar = new WP_Query('post_type=calendar&month=January'); 
while($calendar->have_posts()) : $calendar->the_post(); 
?>              
<div class="grid" style="background:none">

<div class="col-1">
    <h3>
        <?php 
            the_title();
        ?>
    </h3>
    <h4>
        <?php 
            $dateValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rhc_when', true );
            if($dateValue != '') {
                echo $dateValue;
            }; 
            $timeValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rhc_time', true );
            if($timeValue != '') { ?>, <?php
                echo $timeValue;
            }
         ?>                         
    </h4>
    <?php $content = the_content(); 
        if( $content !='') {
            echo $content;
        };
    ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<hr>
<h2>February</h2>
<?php // Annual Events Posts
    $calendar = new WP_Query('post_type=calendar&month=February');
    while($calendar->have_posts()) : $calendar->the_post(); 
?>              
<div class="grid" style="background:none"> 
    <div class="col-1">
        <h3>
            <?php 
                the_title();
            ?>
        </h3>
        <h4>
            <?php 
                $dateValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rhc_when', true );
                if($dateValue != '') {
                    echo $dateValue;
                }; 
                $timeValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rhc_time', true );
                if($timeValue != '') { ?>, <?php
                    echo $timeValue;
                }
            ?>                          
        </h4>
        <?php $content = the_content(); 
            if( $content !='') {
                echo $content;
            };
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: That looks pretty tidy mate, if that code works... I would keep it.

Comment: the_content is an echo function, not a return function. If you want to set the content to a variable before determining whether or not you want to echo it, use get_the_content. Aside from that, as @BradHouston had said, it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: @BradHouston, the loop itself isn't bad but he has to run that 12 times, and pull 12 queries. I think this is an "efficiency" question.

Comment: You can save a little by removing white space i.e
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Slowly but surely getting the hang of php and wordpress, so I'm glad to know, for the most part, what I did was ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that would be incorrect is your use of `the_content()`. If you want to set the Post Content to a variable before determining whether or not you want to echo it, you need to use get_the_content. Apart from that, everything is ok, but I would condense it a little more:

```
<div class="module">
<?php
// Annual Events Posts
$months = array(
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
);
foreach($months as $month){
    $calendar = new WP_Query('post_type=calendar&month='.$month); 
    if($calendar->have_posts()) :
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $month; ?></h2>
    <div class="grid" style="background:none">
    while($calendar->have_posts()) : $calendar->the_post(); 
    ?>
        <div class="col-1">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <h4>
            <?php 
            if($dateValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rhc_when', true ))
                echo "$dateValue, ";
            if($timeValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rhc_time', true ))
                echo $timeValue;
            ?>                         
            </h4>
            <?php
            if($content = get_the_content())
                echo $content;
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php 
    endwhile;
    ?>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
</div>
```

Also, thank you for using WP_Query and not query_posts.

**EDIT:**

I've added a conditional to determine if the grid div and heading needed to be written. Overall, though, your code is pretty solid.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I like your condensed version, so I think I'll go with it. I'm still trying to wrap my head around wordpress, so I'm never sure if I'm doing things the right way!